# PHP SQL Statement not accepting Variable

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use the following code however it is giving me errors.

Code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$action = '['command'=>'get','target'=>'location']';

$query = "UPDATE ZeusUsers SET action = '$action' WHERE notification_id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or exit("Error in query: $query. " . mysqli_error());
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'command'
```

If I change the $action to a standard word the statement works fine, it just seems to have issues with the single quotes and square brackets.

I've also tried using \ in front of the single quotes and it still fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is that $action supposed to be? The syntax is completely broken as is. Should it be an array?

Comment: It's JSON that I need to call later on, so storing it in the DB until I need to call it.

Comment: If `$id` is an int cast it that way as the minimum to prevent injections. `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];`. Other ways to prevent injections, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let php build the json string for you

```
$action = json_encode(array('command'=>'get','target'=>'location'));
```

You are starting and stoping a string literal with the single quotes so php is interpreting `command` as php code but it doesn't know what that keyword is.

Comment: Produces the the following error: `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /assets/scripts/location.php on line 10
Error in query: UPDATE ZeusUsers SET action = '['command'=>'get','target'=>'location']' WHERE notification_id = '1111'. `

Comment: Just used \ before all single quotes and seems to fix it! Thanks!

Comment: just noticed how you are interpolating the $action variable in the query.  You really should be using prepared statements there.  That would have solved the problem and is more secure.